# ng-change not working in custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I have the following custom directive:

```
app.directive('stream', ['BitrateCalculator', function(BitrateCalculator) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'directives/stream.html',
            controller: function() {
            this.codec = '';
            this.fps = 1;
            this.resolution = '';
            this.quality = 1;
            this.bitrate = 16;

            this.calculate = function() {
                console.log('teste')
                this.bitrate = BitrateCalculator.calculate(this.codec, this.resolution, this.quality, this.fps);
            };
        },
        controllerAlias: 'ctrl'
    }
}]);
```

And its template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="encodingCamera">Compressão: </label>
        <select name="encodingCamera" ng-model="ctrl.codec" ng-change="ctrl.calculate()" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="h264" selected>H.264</option>
            <option value="mjpeg">MJPEG</option>
            <option value="mpeg4">MPEG-4</option>
        </select>
<!--        <p ng-show="addCam.encodingCamera.$invalid && addCam.encodingCamera.$dirty">Selecione um valor</p> -->
    </div>
<!-- ... more code ... -->
```

All of that code were previously inside controllers, and the HTML in just one single file. I am now trying to extract the repeated HTML (as it's a tabbed page with mostly the same fields) to custom directives in AngularJS.

Before this refactoring, everything worked fine and the function `calculate()` was being called every time the field changed, but after it, `ngChange` is not working anymore, although the two-way data-binding is still working through `ngModel`.

How is this possible and what do I need to do to make `ngChange` work again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not  fan of having controllers inside directives, you can try to move your logic to the link function, something like this:

```
app.directive('stream', ['BitrateCalculator', function(BitrateCalculator) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'directives/stream.html',
        link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
                elem.bind('change', function(){
                 alert('element changed');
                 // call BitrateCalculator
             });
        }
    }
}]);
```

take a look to this [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives-part-two/) as reference

Answer (score 0):

You should inject scope into your controller please see demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/iWAQx4IOmkz6lMQpgZHy?p=preview

```
app.directive('stream', ['BitrateCalculator',
  function(BitrateCalculator) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope:{},
      templateUrl: 'stream.html',
      controller: function($scope, BitrateCalculator) {

        $scope.codec = '';
        $scope.fps = 1;
        $scope.resolution = 720;
        $scope.quality = 1;
        $scope.bitrate = 16;

        $scope.calculate = function() {
          console.log(BitrateCalculator);

          console.log('teste')
          $scope.bitrate = BitrateCalculator.calculate($scope.codec, $scope.resolution, $scope.quality, $scope.fps);
        };
      },
      controllerAlias: 'ctrl'
    }
  }
]);
```